# Stylesheet on QScrollBar leaves background of scrollbar with checkerboard pattern?

Tags: c++, css, qt, stylesheet

When I style my `QScrollBar` using a stylesheet, the background color is checkered instead of being solid.

```
QScrollBar:horizontal {
    background-color: grey;
}
```

[image]

How do you make the background of the scrollbar a solid color?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

What you are referring to as "the background" is actually the two sub-elements `add-page` and `sub-page`. You need to define the background element on those sub-elements.

The simplest solution would be to remove the `background` on both. Then it would inherit the background color `grey` that you have already set on `QScrollBar`:

```
QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal, QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal {
    background: none;
}
```

[image]

But if desired, you could style each individually to your liking:

```
QScrollBar::sub-page:horizontal {
    background: red;
}

QScrollBar::add-page:horizontal {
    background: green;
}
```

[image]

[Source.](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/12557-Scrollbar-background-does-not-go-solid-%28-%29-when-using-stylesheets)

Unfortunately, this solution is rather hard to divine from the [official documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html).