# PyQt5 - setStyleSheet transparent/alpha not working?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm currently writing some program using PyQt5, and I wanted to style the scrollbar in the UI

```
QScrollBar:horizontal {
    border: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: yellow;
    height: 15px;
    margin: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}

QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
    background: rgb(100,100,104);
    min-width: 20px;
}

QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal {
    border: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: yellow;
    width: 20px;
    subcontrol-position: right;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {
    border: 0px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: yellow;
    subcontrol-position: left;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
```

but it doesn't really show up when I run the program.

[image]

I also tried styling other items in the UI, this time by adding the stylesheets inline.

```
self.content = QTextEdit()
self.content.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit {border: 5px solid transparent}")
```

but this shows up:

[image]

Isn't that border supposed to be transparent? I've tried styling other items, but I just can't seem to make the transparent styling work. I've also tried using `rgba(0,0,0,0)` instead of transparent and I get the same results. Is there something I'm missing here?

EDIT: Here's the MRE as requested by @musicamante

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.stylesheet_filename = "qss/styles.qss"
        self.loadStyleSheet(self.stylesheet_filename)

        self.setGeometry(200,200,800,600)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        
        self.scene = MainScene()
        self.view = QGraphicsView()

        self.view.setScene(self.scene)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.view)

        self.show()

    def loadStyleSheet(self, filename):
        print('Style loading: ', filename)
        file = QFile(filename)
        file.open(QFile.ReadOnly | QFile.Text)
        stylesheet = file.readAll()
        QApplication.instance().setStyleSheet(str(stylesheet, encoding='utf-8'))

class MainScene(QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setSceneRect(-1000,-1000,2000,2000)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QColor("#252629"))
        self.card = Card()
        self.addItem(self.card)


class Card(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)    

        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsSelectable)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)  
        
        self.content = Content()

        self.grContent = QGraphicsProxyWidget(self)
        self.content.setGeometry(10,15, 280, 150)
        self.grContent.setWidget(self.content)

    def boundingRect(self):
        return QRectF(0,0,300,180).normalized()

    def paint(self, painter, QStyleOptionGraphicsItem, widget=None):
        #background
        path_background = QPainterPath()
        path_background.addRect(0,0,300,180)
        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor("#998090")))
        painter.drawPath(path_background.simplified())


class Content(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.content = QTextEdit('I want the background of this QTextEdit and the scrollbar tracks to be transparent, not white.')
        self.content.setStyleSheet("QTextEdit {border: 0px; background-color: transparent}")
        
        self.layout.addWidget(self.content)
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

EDIT 2: And I forgot to paste the qss code:

```
QScrollBar:horizontal {
    border: 0px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    height: 15px;
    margin: 0px 20px 0 20px;
}
QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
    background: red;
    min-width: 20px;
}
QScrollBar::add-line:horizontal {
    border: 0px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    width: 20px;
    subcontrol-position: right;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}

QScrollBar::sub-line:horizontal {
    border: 0px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    width: 20px;
    subcontrol-position: left;
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
}
```

Comment: Please, don't post code as images, it makes it impossible to copy/paste and test it. Edit your post, remove the images and follow the suggestions about [formatting code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) to correctly add the code. Then, what do you mean by "transparent"? Do you want to "see through" the window (being able to see the windows behind it or even the desktop)?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it with the actual code on the post... By transparent I meant being able to see through the item, like in the QTextEdit example, there shouldn't be any border there because I set the border color to transparent, but instead there's that grayish border.  The same thing happens with the scroll bar.

Comment: "transparent" means that you can see the color of what's behind, if the parent(s) has no stylesheet background set, you will see the default system background. Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It's important that we know the widget structure and exactly where you set those stylesheets. You're not using a QGraphicsProxyWidget, are you?

Comment: I see.. I am using QGraphicsProxyWidget for the QTextEdit. I had it added inside a QGraphicsItem object... which I don't think you could set a styleSheet to..

Comment: As I thought. Stylesheets can become very tricky when used in complex widgets like scroll areas (as QTextEdit) *and* as proxy widgets. If you want to see through the graphics item, there might be some workaround, but we still need you to provide a MRE to begin with.

Comment: @musicamante edited the post with the MRE code

Comment: You have two different issues here: one is for the scrollbars of the graphics view, and the other is for the textedit. Can you clarify exactly what is the expected output? Do you want that all scrollbars look the same, with the background of their widget?

Comment: @Beso It seems like you've been suggesting a lot of edits that apply code formatting to words that aren't code. Please don't. I suggest you read [Inline Code Spans should not be used for emphasis, right?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112/349538) and [Should I use code blocks when mentioning framework names/technologies?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360491/4284627).

Comment: @musicamante Yeah.. I want to achieve the same effect that you get when you set overflow to overlay in css... As for the TextEdit, I just want to see the card item underneath it

Comment: @DonaldDuck thank you very much for suggestion. I do.

Answer (score 1):

While it might seem that the concepts of "standard" css can be applied to Qt StyleSheets (QSS), that is only true for the basic aspects of syntax and inheritance: QSS only implements *some* of the CSS 2.1 specification, and does *not* allow layout management (except for borders, margins and padding within the specific widget), which is exclusive responsibility of Qt.

This is very important when trying to set a "transparent" background for a scroll bar, because Qt doesn't allow the "overflow" effect of CSS, since the scrollbars are generally drawn *outside* the contents of the viewport.

In order to achieve a similar effect, the solution is to correctly set the background of the scroll area (the QGraphicsView, in your case).

```
QGraphicsView { 
    background: #252629; 
}
```

Note that, for various reasons, it's not always enough to set a generic stylesheet on the application, and it's sometimes required to explicitly set the scrollbar-dedicated stylesheet *on* the scroll bars (`self.view.horizontalScrollBar().setStyleSheet(...)`, `self.view.verticalScrollBar().setStyleSheet(...)`).

Then, the problem with the widget in the QGraphicsScene is different. When adding a QGraphicsProxyWidget, the widget is considered as a *top level* window, so it will have its own background, based on the application palette (which seems white, but it's a light gray). The solution, in this case, is the same as when trying to show a "transparent" window:

```
class Content(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer... The solution you gave for the QProxyWidget worked - it now looks the way I wanted... However the scroll bars are still a problem.. I set the styles for QGraphicsView, and added the styles for the scrollbars inline, and when I run the code I get these screentone-like patterns on the scrollbar track..

Comment: @NumpyNoob what do you mean by "screentone-like patterns on the scrollbar track"?

Comment: Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17935691/stylesheet-on-qscrollbar-leaves-background-of-scrollbar-with-checkerboard-patter I tried the solution on that post and it didn't work